# Flash cache is not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Greetings, why is it that my flash resources are not put in cache?
I use AS2,
Here's my html:

```
<object classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' codebase='http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0' width=544 height=544 id=destiny align=middle> 
 <param name=allowScriptAccess value=sameDomain /> 
 <param name=movie value=http://mkdev/e/other/flash/villages/destiny.swf /> 
 <param name=menu value=false /> 
 <param name=quality value=best /> 
 <param name=wmode value=transparent /> 
 <param name=bgcolor value='#66cccc' /> 
 <embed src=http://mkdev/e/other/flash/villages/destiny.swf menu=false quality=best wmode=transparent bgcolor='#66cccc' width=544 height=544 name=destiny align=middle allowScriptAccess=sameDomain type='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' /> 
 </object>
```

My images are loaded with

```
mcl.loadClip("http://mkdev/g/generated/100x100/tile_" + numTile + ".jpg", ord);
```

Comment: How do you determine that the images are not cached? Are you allowing cache in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, Flash has nothing to do with whether loaded resources get cached. When you load things, Flash just passes the request along to the browser and waits for a response, so Flash has no influence over whether the response comes out of cache, or whether the response gets cached. Indeed, from inside Flash you can't even tell whether you're getting cached responses or not, unless you examine the response headers or guess based on timing.

So I can't help much with your issue, but I can advise you to look elsewhere for the problem!

Comment: Agreed. Also, try using Charles or Fiddler to spy on the requests.